# pl/sql update procedure with cursor gets stuck

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, plsqldeveloper

i wrote a program that uses cursor in order to update some row in these table- here is the program:

```
DECLARE
   -- Local variables here
   CURSOR s
   IS
      (SELECT UNIQUE *
         FROM Sellers
        WHERE ID_Seller NOT IN (SELECT ID_Seller
                                  FROM Sellers NATURAL JOIN Sales));

   s_rec   Sellers%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   -- Test statements here
   OPEN s;

   LOOP
      FETCH s INTO s_rec;

      EXIT WHEN s%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (s_rec.ID_Seller);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (s_rec.Salary);
      updateSalary (s_rec.ID_Seller, s_rec.Salary - 50);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE s;
END;
```

this is the procedure updateSalary:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateSalary (ID_S        IN VARCHAR2,
                                          newSalary   IN FLOAT)
IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE Sellers s
      SET s.salary = newSalary
    WHERE s.ID_Seller = ID_S;
END updateSalary;
```

when running the program, it get stuck at the update command.
what is wrong with the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

in order to update a table inside a cursor you need to open the cursor in a "FOR UPDATE" mode , add to your query "FOR UPDATE" :

```
(SELECT UNIQUE *
     FROM Sellers
    WHERE ID_Seller NOT IN (SELECT ID_Seller
                              FROM Sellers NATURAL JOIN Sales) FOR UPDATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add **FOR UPDATE** IN CURSOR TO UPDATE THE TABLE
```